# Asterisk: How to stop conference1 to hear from conference2 when a user is connected to both

Tags: asterisk

Our requirements are:

1. User sends audio only to conference1, ie does not send audio to conference2.
2. User receives audio only from conference2, ie does not receive audio from conference1.
3. Conference1 should not hear the audio of conference2

Failed attempt 1
 - We placed user in his conference room (say userConf).
 - We originated local channels from userConf to conference1 and conference2.
 - Using manageraction_muteAudio we implemented first two constraints. 
This attempt failed because userConf carried the audio of conference2 to conference1.

Failed attempt 2
 - We placed user in conference2 muted.
 - We used chanspy to listen to user.
This attempt failed because we did not know how to take chanspy leg to conference1.

Any suggestion on the above two failed attempts or a new way to solving this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: it work ok based on chanspy/local channels. Dialplan will be complex, more then 2hrs of debug expected.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using meetme conferences, you can use:

```
meetme mute|unmute <confno> <userno>
```

on one of the conferences to mute him, and he will be able to speak on the other conference

Comment: But they are using Asterisk.

Comment: Asterisk is the service, meetme is an application/addon in Asterisk itself!